# Recursively delete all empty folders in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a command to execute in Bash that deletes all empty folders recursively until there is no empty folder in the tree? I could execute this:

```
find . -type d -empty | xargs -I '{}' rmdir {}
```

repeatedly until there is no more empty folders, but I am looking for something a bit more efficient. Especially since that to know whether there are empty folders left, I would have to execute the same command, i.e. two calls to `find . -type d -empty` in each iteration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is simple, given the [GNU `find` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size):

```bash
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

This will delete empty directories; since the `-delete` option implies the `-depth` option, it will delete directories that only had empty directories underneath them, so there's no need to run it multiple times.

Comment: This was not working properly for me where I was specifying multiple paths and I discovered that I needed to place my ORed `-path` instructions before `-delete` into a group like this: `find / -type d -empty \( -path /pathA -or -path /pathB \) -delete`